# dynamic input into ajax call for api

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, smartystreets

I am trying to assign a variable to my form input data which is of json format and url-encoded. At least that is what I think I'm doing with jquery: serializeArray() and param(). This is the error code that I'm getting: https://api.smartystreets.com/street-address/?auth-token=0123456789&callback=jQuery#Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Some of the submitted street address requests are incomplete.)

The main question I have is: how to get user input from form to variable and then put that into the ajax call? When I use:

```
data: {
                    'auth-token': '0123456789',      
                    'street': '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway',
                    'city': 'Mountain View',
                    'state': 'CA',
                    'zipCode': '94043',
                    'candidates': 1
                },
```

in place of:

```
data: $.param(myData),
```

I get the json response back, but otherwise I get the mentioned error-code.

The code:

```
 <pre id="results"></pre>
     <form action="" name="address" method="post" id="address">
          Street Address
          <input type="textbox" id="street_add" name="street_add">
          <br />
          City
          <input type="textbox"  id="city" name="city">
          <br />
          State
          <input type="textbox" id="state" name="state">
          <br />
          Zipcode
          <input type="textbox"  id="zipcode" name="zipcode">
          <br />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" />
     </form>
    <script>
    var myData = $("form #address").serializeArray();
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.smartystreets.com/street-address/?auth-token=0123456789',
                dataType: 'JSONP',  // NOTE: This is what allows the cross-domain ajax call.
                data: $.param(myData),
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    var pretty = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4).replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;').replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
                    $('#results').html(pretty);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("form #address")` should be `$("form#address")` or simply `$("#address")` to select the form.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to serialize the form data is:

```
var myData = $("form#address").serialize();
```

Then in the `.ajax` function:

```
 data: myData,
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/